# Why e.target.value cannot be used directly to setState in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple form where a user can select a set of skills (Python, C++, Java - multiple select using Bootstrap) and submit the form.

**How I set the state of the array**

```
function handleSkills(e){
    let newElement = e.target.value
    setSkills(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);
}
```

**But** if I do it as follow:

```
function handleSkills(e){
    let newElement = e.target.value
    setSkills(oldArray => [...oldArray, e.target.value]);
}
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I would like to know why this occurs.
I was thinking that would have been ok to use using directly `e.target.value` instead of assigning it to a variable, however, it turns out is not ok. Do you know why?

**My Component**

```
function MyForm() {
    const [skills, setSkills] = React.useState([])


function handleSkills(e){
    let newElement = e.target.value
    setSkills(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);
}

function handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}

return(
        <div style={{marginTop: "100px", marginRight: "50px", marginLeft: "50px"}}>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Card style={{paddingBottom: "10px"}}>
                        <Container>
                            <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Label>Add Skills</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control as="select" multiple onChange={handleSkills}>
                                        <option>Python</option>
                                        <option>Java</option>
                                        <option>Ruby/Rails</option>
                                        <option>C++</option>
                                        <option>Backend</option>
                                    </Form.Control>
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                    Add Skills
                                </Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Container>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
)

}
```

If I pass directly `e.target.value` in `setSkills` I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

I would like to know why this occurs.

Comment: `e` is a `SyntheticEvent` an it probably becomes invalid by the time the callback function is executed. [DOCUMENTATION](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)